# Problem with VioLens mod in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I installed the VioLens mod from Nexus, but I can't customize my kill moves . Whatever I choose simply won't enable. For example, I choose Grab Stab, but when I kill an enemy, my character just cut his head off. No matter which kill move I enable, my character just cut the enemy's head off.
Can someone please give me a solution?

Comment: Are you using the Mod Organizer (or a similar mod platform)?

Comment: I use Nexus Mod Manager and Loot but why? is it because of NMM

Comment: Are you using the MCM to configure kill moves? My setup looks like [this](https://imgur.com/yAJojSa) and [this](https://imgur.com/O2TgsnL). Notice the 100% killmove chance.

Comment: my kill move chance is 100% too and my character perform the kill move but he just cut the enemy's head . I can't customize them.

Comment: So VioLens is saving all other preferences?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things in VioLens MCM setup that you can try. My setup looks like below.

[image: VioLens MCM Screen 1]
[image]

If all you are seeing are decapitations, there are a couple of things you can do.

1. You can set *Advancing Killmoves* to *ON*. It will place any unused
   killmoves into the rotation.
2. You can lower the *Decapitation Chance* to a lower value. Or you could turn it off if you never want to see decapitations.

You can also try setting *Killmoves* to *Customized* which will let you customize the mod even further. Full documentation can be found at the [mod page](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/668) on Nexus.